# How would I pivot this object using linq?

Tags: c#, linq

If I have the following objects.

```
public class CFS
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public IList<Topic> Topics { get; set; }
    public IList<Status> Status { get; set; }
}

public class Topic
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

How can I put it into the following object where Topic.ID == Status.ID && Status.Name = "pass"? The Topic and Status string values would be the Topic.Name and Status.Name values respectively. The list of string can be the FirstName, email, whatever, that part is trivial. I realize Topic and Status expose the same properties but that's just for this example.

```
public class SelectedTopic
{
    public string Topic { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Person { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried several combinations of SelectMany, Any, Join and I can't seem to pivot the data the way I want.

Comment: I don't understand, each user has a list of topics and a disjointed list of status.  You want to find all topics and status items that have the same id value and then add those to your list or append the user to the existing one?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit what you want to achieve? Show some example of the desired data transformation and your attempts to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you would want to do this but here is how:

```
void Main()
{
  List<Topic> topicA = new List<Topic>() { new Topic() { ID = 1, Name = "1" }, new Topic() {ID = 2 , Name = "2"}, new Topic() {ID = 3, Name = "3" } };
  List<Topic> topicB = new List<Topic>() { new Topic() { ID = 2, Name = "2" }, new Topic() {ID = 3 , Name = "3"}, new Topic() {ID = 4, Name = "4" } };
  List<Topic> topicC = new List<Topic>() { new Topic() { ID = 1, Name = "1" } };
  List<Topic> topicD = new List<Topic>() { new Topic() {ID = 2 , Name = "2"}, new Topic() {ID = 3, Name = "3" } };

  List<Status> statusA = new List<Status>() { new Status() { ID = 1, Name = "pass" }, new Status() {ID = 2 , Name = "2"}, new Status() {ID = 3, Name = "3" } };
  List<Status> statusB = new List<Status>() { new Status() { ID = 2, Name = "2" }, new Status() {ID = 3 , Name = "pass"}, new Status() {ID = 4, Name = "pass" } };
  List<Status> statusC = new List<Status>() { new Status() { ID = 1, Name = "pass" } };
  List<Status> statusD = new List<Status>() { new Status() {ID = 2 , Name = "2"}, new Status() {ID = 3, Name = "pass" } };


  List<CFS> test = new List<CFS>() { 
                      new CFS() { FirstName = "A", LastName = "A", Email = "A@A.com", Topics = topicA, Status = statusA },
                      new CFS() { FirstName = "B", LastName = "B", Email = "B@B.com", Topics = topicB, Status = statusB },
                      new CFS() { FirstName = "C", LastName = "C", Email = "C@C.com", Topics = topicC, Status = statusC },
                      new CFS() { FirstName = "D", LastName = "D", Email = "D@D.com", Topics = topicD, Status = statusD },
  };


  var result = test.SelectMany(x => x.Topics.SelectMany((t) => x.Status, (topic,status) => new { CFS = x, T = topic, S = status }))
                    .Where(x => x.S.Name == "pass" &&  x.T.ID == x.S.ID)
                    .Select(x => new {  first = x.CFS.FirstName, status = x.S.Name, topic = x.T.Name})
                    .GroupBy(x => x.topic)
                    .Select(x => new SelectedTopic { Topic = x.Key, Status = "pass", Person = x.Select(z => z.first).Distinct().ToList() })
                    .Dump();

}
```

Tested in LinqPad -- if you are not using this tool I suggest you do so.

Comment: That did it, thanks. I know it's a weird model. I basically have a list of user data that has disconnected lists within it that contain items those users have applied for and then someone else's grading of one or more of those applications. I was then asked for a view of applied for items and users that meet a certain criteria of scoring for each application. I had done it with nested loops and by abstracting the lists out of the original object but I was curious to see how it could be done with the data model I'd been given.

Comment: What would the syntax look like if there were another level of nesting? Suppose there were another nest key value pair list that also had matching IDs (Keys).

Comment: Just use zip to add it